# Get row total price from a configurable product in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm writing a payment module, and after the checkout process I'm doing the following to get the price for each product.

```
foreach($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item)
{
//...
$price = (float)$item->getData('row_total_incl_tax');
//...
```

Afaik it works with any kind of product except configurable ones. How can I retrieve the row total for a configurable product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems [`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Sales/Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item.html) has an [`isChildrenCalculated`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Sales/Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item.html#isChildrenCalculated) method. If true you can use [`getChildrenItems`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Sales/Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item.html#getChildrenItems)to either list the simple products individually or loop through them and add up their row totals.